# Can't create Hive table through JDBC connection

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am running Hive2 on my ubuntu and trying to create tables both through the hive interface and through beeline\jdbc.
I have no problem creating tables through hive interface but when accessing through jdbc I get a permission denied error.

```
 FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException Permission denied: user=hive, access=WRITE, inode="/user/hive/warehouse/page_view":cto:supergroup:drwxrwxr-x
```

From the exception I see it is trying to create the table in a directory which does not exist (/user/hive/warehouse/...)

my `hive-default.xml` has the following configuration:

```
<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/apache-hive-1.2.1-bin/metastore_db</value>
    <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value/>
    <description>Thrift URI for the remote metastore. Used by metastore client to connect to remote metastore.</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.connect.retries</name>
    <value>3</value>
    <description>Number of retries while opening a connection to metastore</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.failure.retries</name>
    <value>1</value>
    <description>Number of retries upon failure of Thrift metastore calls</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.client.connect.retry.delay</name>
    <value>1s</value>
    <description>
      Expects a time value with unit (d/day, h/hour, m/min, s/sec, ms/msec, us/usec, ns/nsec), which is sec if not specified.
      Number of seconds for the client to wait between consecutive connection attempts
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.client.socket.timeout</name>
    <value>600s</value>
    <description>
      Expects a time value with unit (d/day, h/hour, m/min, s/sec, ms/msec, us/usec, ns/nsec), which is sec if not specified.
      MetaStore Client socket timeout in seconds
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.client.socket.lifetime</name>
    <value>0s</value>
    <description>
      Expects a time value with unit (d/day, h/hour, m/min, s/sec, ms/msec, us/usec, ns/nsec), which is sec if not specified.
      MetaStore Client socket lifetime in seconds. After this time is exceeded, client
      reconnects on the next MetaStore operation. A value of 0s means the connection
      has an infinite lifetime.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>mine</value>
    <description>password to use against metastore database</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.ds.connection.url.hook</name>
    <value/>
    <description>Name of the hook to use for retrieving the JDO connection URL. If empty, the value in javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL is used</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.Multithreaded</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>Set this to true if multiple threads access metastore through JDO concurrently.</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/usr/local/apache-hive-1.2.1-bin/metastore_db;create=true</value>
    <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>
```

**So why it is trying to create the metastore_db under /user/hive/warehouse?**

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I did not change the `hive-default.xml.template` name to `hive-site.xml` as I should.